# Is it safe to use split().body() when the exchange may or may not contain an iterable in the body?

Tags: apache-camel

So, say we have the follwing (simplified) route setup:

```
RouteDefination routeDef = from("seda:somewhereIrrelevant")
                               .process(someProcessor1); // normal message.

if ( typeOfRoute.equals("requiresList"){
    routeDef.process(addsAListToBody); // creates list out of normal message.
}

routeDef.split().body()
        .process(oneMessageAtATime) // this is regardless of whether it was originally a part of a list.
        .end();
```

The thing is, I can see that this works with or without `"addsAListToBody"` Processor. It we pass a normal object of type `Foo` it passes on the exchange to "oneMessageAtATime" Processor. If the route contains `"addsAListToBody"` Processor that returns a `List<Foo>` then it splits the list into `Foo` elements that get processed one by one.

The thing is, this seems like a very simple thing that solves what I want to do but for some reason it feels like it's wrong.

Is this "conditional" useage of splitter correct? Or am I doing something wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is totally OK, nothing wrong here (as your findings confirm).

- if the body contains something "splittable" (iterable), it is splitted
- if not, the whole body is passed on (it is treated like a single element list)

This is very convenient since you do not need to create pseudo lists from single objects before passing them to the [splitter](https://camel.apache.org/components/latest/eips/split-eip.html).